# Programmatically include multiple images to a markdown document

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is there any way to include multiple images in markdown?
Instead of typing:

```
![](results/Images/experiment1_a.png "a")
![](results/Images/experiment1_b.png "b")
![](results/Images/experiment1_c.png "c")
```

Maybe it is possible to do:

```
![](results/Images/experiment1_*.png)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can to do it with the help of Pander package

```
library(pander)
pander::pandoc.image(image_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no possible ways to include multiple images in GFM.

But if you are writing plain HTML you can leverage JavaScript to do this work.